# how to create a script that allows to use the path list as a reference for copying files in PowerShell in .bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, copy, ntfs

I'm looking for a way to automate archiving where after I plug my two external drives I can copy all my resources. The problem is that I have different file structures on my laptop and on both external drives so I need to select specific folders to be copied. It means that I can't select one root folder and copy it straightforward. I tried to find a way to declare more than one path in the `cp` command and in the `copy` command, without success. An example path:

/my_programming_stuff

```
              /folder1
              /folder2
              /folder3
              /folder4
```

I want to select only the first 3 folders to copy them into **external drive1** and **external drive 2**. The idea is to create a `.bat` file that will copy everything at once ( in the best case scenario it will be copied simultaneously on both external drives, so it will be much faster). Another problem is that there needs to be a bypass the ntfs long path limitations (max. 260 characters).
Flags that I want to use:

- Copy the files and directories and all of their attributes,
  including ownerships and permissions.
- Recursively copy directories and their contents.
- When copying files from one directory to another, only
  copy files that either doesn't exist or are newer than the
  existing corresponding files, in the destination
  directory.
- data verification (so it's certain that the copy was verified)
- progression bar with time eta

Until now I was using Total Commander to do this but every day I need to pick only a few folders to be copied which takes time and is inefficient.

I have experience with Bash and PowerShell but I am not sure how to handle this topic.

Comment: Source and destination for `COPY`, `XCOPY` and `ROBOCOPY` all only one entry.  `XCOPY` and `ROBOCOPY` have exclude options.  If you know which three folders you want then just use a `FOR` command to cycle through them and pass that to `ROBOCOPY`. `FOR %%G IN ("Folder1" "Folder2" "Folder3") DO Robocopy "%%~G" "destination"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a static batch file with robocopy commands.  I think /copyall is the only switch you need to specify for all this.  Other defaults should satisfy requirements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0):

I think your time will be better spent learning how to use either [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/) or [FreeFileSynce](https://freefilesync.org/).  I used FreeFileSync some years ago but got disgusted with the it's constantly changing format of its xml file used for starting a backup, so I switched to FastCopy.  But it looks like FreeFileSync may be getting their act together and I aim to do some experiments over the summer to see if I want to switch back to it.

Both can handle the long filename format issues, both can be executed by a batch file, both seem to have a lot of quality, but FreeFileSync has more features - and more bloated because of the features.  But speed wise, I think FastCopy is probably one of the better products out there and very streamline in use and design.